# Is there a user friendly desktop software that encrypts given text using PGP or GPG?

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

I was searching for a simple software that encrypts given text using either PGP or GPG. The alternatives I have found so far are very complicated and hard to operate.

Are there any encryption programs that generates public and private key, encrypts/decrypts text given proper key?

Comment: Probably better asked at  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) might be your best bet.  **Assemetric encryption is already a pretty complicated topic** and would be pretty hard to dumb down any further.  Still, it looks as if this particular software at least **provides a GUI to navigate around in as opposed other command line tools** like [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/).

The only downside I can see is they throw in a few extra added features that you may not use.

On the other side, **if you don't require assemetric** encryption, you can always use a **WinZIP** or **WinRAR** to encrypt as long as you **use a strong password** (at least 8 character, using numbers, upper, lower, special characters, etc)

Comment: I think it's https://www.openpgp.org/software/kleopatra/ now.

Answer (score 0):

In the GNOME 2 builds that ship with GPG (such as Debian or Ubuntu) this is built-in; you just right-click the file and select "Encrypt..." and you are prompted to pick the public keys you wish to use.

I'm not sure which program provides this functionality, it's probably a plugin to nautilus.

You may have luck with GPGME (GPG Made Easy) which apparently has Win32 builds.
http://freecode.com/projects/gpgme

Please re-tag your question with the operating system you're interested in.